# How to address internal module when a name conflict exists in TypeScript

Tags: module, namespaces, typescript

In my TypeScript project (using only internal modules), I want to include polyfills/extension for an existing library. For this example, I will use the RxJS library but the question/problem is not specific to this library.

The following code is what I came up with:

```
module MyModule.Rx {
    Rx.Observable.prototype.myExtension = function() { /* ... */ };
}
```

The RxJS definitions (.d.ts files) are used and compiled together with the code. This leads to the following compiler error: `2339 Property 'Observable' does not exist on type 'typeof Rx'`

As far as I can tell this happens because I used the same `Rx` identifier in `MyModule.Rx`. When switching the namespace in the first line to `module MyModule.NotRx {` everything works fine - the `Observable` type is correctly looked up from the RxJS .d.ts file.

So it seems that the names `MyModule.Rx` and the RxJS declared `Rx` namespaces are in conflict. I know that I could simply rename my namespace to  `MyModule.SomethingElse` but that seems somewhat of a hack.

Having all polyfills/extensions for `Rx` in the `MyModue.Rx` namespace seems a natural choice for me - how can this be done in a clean way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do that.

Take this code in TypeScript:

```
var B = 'test';
module A.B {
    // Declare a function
    export function fn() {
    }
    // Tests
    console.log(B); // Object {  }
    A.B.fn(); // valid
    B.fn(); // valid
    fn(); // valid
}
```

The message displayed in the console is: `Object {  }` and not `test`. Look at the transpiled code:

```
var B = 'test'; // root scope
var A;
(function (A) {
    var B; // same name, hide the root scope one
    (function (B) {
        // Declare a function
        function fn() {
        }
        B.fn = fn;
        // Tests
        console.log(B); // Object {  }
        A.B.fn(); // valid
        B.fn(); // valid
        fn(); // valid
    })(B = A.B || (A.B = {}));
})(A || (A = {}));
```

The module `A.B` is transpiled to two JavaScript variables `A` and `B`. We can use them in order to access to the exported members of the module: the function `fn` is accessible from `A.B.fn`, `B.fn` and `fn`. In the module, the variable `B` from the root scope is hidden by the variable `B` of the module.

You can't access to a global variable `Rx` from a module named `Rx`.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by Tarh you cannot refer to an outer module if its been shadowed by a local variable. I've +1ed his answer and that should be the accepted answer. I'll just leave a few workarounds:

One workaround which you already know is to rename `MyModule.Rx` to something that doesn't have `Rx`. An alternative is to capture `Rx` with some other name:

```
import OrigRx = Rx;
module MyModule.Rx {
    OrigRx.Observable.prototype.myExtension = function() { /* ... */ };
}
```

This is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021964/390330

Comment: `OrigRx.Observable.prototype...`, no?