# Inner module with the same name as outer one

Tags: typescript

I have definitions for some javascript library. Let's say that it functions can be accessed via module name Lib.

At the same time I've created my module like this:

```js
module Outer.Lib.Inner {
  // some code
}
```

How can i access outer module Lib inside my own module Outer.Lib.Inner? I've tried it that way:

```js
module Outer.Lib.Inner {
  function SomeFunction(): void {
    // here i am trying to access outer Lib module but compiler thinks i am accessing my Outer.Lib module
    Lib. ....
  
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean, `Outer.Lib.Inner.Lib`?

Comment: No, I mean that somewhere exists module Lib and I've referenced it. At the same time I have my own module named Outer.Lib.Inner. How can I access methods of 3rd party module Lib inside my module Outer.Lib.Inner?  Compiler thinks that I am trying to access my own module Outer.Lib but I want to access 3rd party referenced module Lib.

Comment: Ah, I misread your sentence. As is usual, basarat has the correct answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how can I qualify the name of the outer module in this situation?

Since the fully qualified name of the outer module `Lib` conflicts with the inner module declaration we are in `Outer.Lib` you need to create an alias:

```
var ExternalLib = Lib; 
// or if you have it in TypeScript: 
// import ExternalLib = Lib;


module Outer.Lib.Inner {
  function SomeFunction(): void {
    // here i am trying to access outer Lib module but compiler thinks i am accessing my Outer.Lib module
    ExternalLib. ....

  }
}
```

Comment: @basarat But this would result in a globally scoped variable (member of window object in browser) called ExternalLib. Besides the uglyness, what if another module (possibly third party lib vendor) choses the same alias name? They would collide and result in unexpected results.

Comment: @dyna it's no more ugly than it being called Lib globally beforehand